# Introducir datos de fichero en array bidimensional

Tags: c

Hola buenas mi problema es el siguiente: Dispongo de un fichero de texto en el que se encuentra dibujado un laberinto y tengo que cargarlo a un array bidimensional (matriz) para poder trabajar con ella, he intentado utilizar fgets pero no funciona como debería y he pensado que la mejor opcion es leerlo caracter a caracter pero acaba haciendo cosas raras el programa a pesar de que no da ningun error el compilador. El codigo del programa que tengo es el siguiente:

Declaro las bibliotecas y el struct con el bidimensional que voy a utilizar

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
> #include <stdlib.h>
> #include <string.h>
> #define FIL 15
> #define COL 30
>
> typedef struct //Declaro el tablero del laberinto como struct dado
> {              //que posteriormente tengo que añadirle mas datos y 
>                 //asi es mas comoda su manipulacion
> char Laberinto [FIL][COL]
>
> }Tablero;
> ```

Este es el main del programa

> ```
> int main()
> {
> char fichero[N];
> Tablero tab;
> FILE *f;
>
> printf("\n\tIntroduce el nombre del fichero del que desea cargar el tablero. ");
> gets(fichero);
>
> f = fopen(fichero , "r");
> ValidarApertura(&*f);
> CargarTablero(&*f , &tab);
> getchar();
>
> return 0;
> }
> ```

Y la funcion que utilizo para cargar el fichero en el bidimensional es la siguiente:

> ```
> void CargarTablero(FILE *f , Tablero *tab)
> {
> char aux;  //Aqui ya esta validada la apertura del fichero y
> int i , j; //lo abre correctamente y el paso de parametros esta correcto
>
> while(aux != EOF)
> {
>     for(i = 0; i < FIL - 1; i++)
>     {
>         for (j = 0; j < COL -1; j++ )
>         {
>             aux = fgetc(f);
>             tab->Laberinto[i][j] = aux;
>             printf("%c",tab->Laberinto[i][j]);
>
>         }
>     }
>
> }
> fclose(f);
>
> }
> ```

El contenido del fichero que tengo que leer y guardar en el bidimensionale es esto:

```
##############################
###### ##########            E
###### ########## ############
######            ############
########### ##################
########### ##################
#####                  #######
##### ##### ##### ############
##### ##### ##### ############
##       ## ##  ##############
##### ##### ##################
##### ##### ##################
##### ##### ##################
###########                  S
##############################
```

Y al ejecutarlo y cargar el fichero aparece lo siguiente por pantalla:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de como puedo hacer? Muchas gracias

Comment: hay algo mal con los saltos de linea del archivo de entrada? donde los estas validando?

Comment: Los voy controlando con el bucle for dado que al llegar al ultimo caracter, aumento en 1 las filas con lo cual el siguiente caracter que guarde lo hara en una linea distinta a la actual

Comment: No he podido reproducir tu problema, el único error que tuve fue `gets(fichero)` es **peligroso** y no debería ser usado, luego que el identificador `N` no existe, asumí que es una macro de preprocesador así que la definí y que falta el `;` al final del `char Laberinto[][]`, pero no obtuve ningún problema extraño al ejecutar tu programa, prueba a crear un nuevo archivo con los datos que has puesto aquí.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hola.**

**Antes de pasar al problema, permiteme hacerte algunas recomendaciones:**

1.- Te falta un ';' en la parte de la declaración de la estructura, aunque no te da error por que posee un solo dato, deberías colocarlo:

```
typedef struct {
   char Laberinto [FIL][COL];
}Tablero;
```

2.- No utilices la función `gets()` ya que esta se encuentra descontinuada, puedes utilizar en su lugar `scanf()` o `fgets()`; la diferencia entre estas dos ultimas es que scanf() lee una cadena hasta que encuentre un salto de linea o un espacio en blanco por lo tanto no podrás leer una cadena del tipo "cadena de texto", solo leerá "cadena" con la función `fgets()` si puedes leer la linea completa, te recomiendo mirar un poco la documentación de estas dos funciones. En este caso como el nombre del archivo no debería contener espacios utilicemos `scanf()`:

```
printf("\n\tIntroduce el nombre del fichero del que desea cargar el tablero: ");
scanf("%s", &fichero);
```

**Ahora si vamos con el problema**

aunque validas con el `while()` que `(aux != EOF)` no lo estas realizando dentro del ciclo de repetición de los `for()`, al agregar esta validación se resuelve el problema, te quedaría algo como esto:

```
  while(aux != EOF)
  {
    for(i = 0; i < FIL-1; i++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < COL-1; j++ )
      {
        aux = fgetc(f);

        if(aux == EOF)
          break;

        tab->Laberinto[i][j] = aux;
        printf("%c",tab->Laberinto[i][j]);

      }
    }
  }
```

PD: revisa los indices de los `for()`, si colocas la condición < creo que no deberías restarle -1.

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias ya funciona :))

Comment: Siempre a la orden.